# The curious case of the missing exclamation mark in CMD files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have whittled down a more complex CMD script to the essentials. It reads an input file line by line, unquotes it (if quoted) and writes it out to another CMD file.

The problem is that if the input file contains exclamation marks (! or bang) the character gets stripped out somewhere along the line.

Here is the CMD script, BANG1.CMD:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if exist bang2.cmd del bang2.cmd
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (bang1.txt) do call :doit1 %%a
exit /b

:doit1
set P1=%1
if %P1%. EQU . exit /b
call :unquotex P1 %P1%
echo>>bang2.cmd echo P1:[%P1%]
exit /b

:unquotex
set X=%2
set Q=%X:~0,1%
if "!Q!" EQU ^""" SET X=!X:~1,-1!
set %1=%X%
exit /b
```

Here is the input file BANG1.TXT:

```
HelloWorld
"Hello World"
Hello!World
"Hello!World"
```

The resulting file BANG2.CMD ends up containing this:

```
echo P1:[HelloWorld]
echo P1:[Hello World]
echo P1:[HelloWorld]
echo P1:[HelloWorld]
```

The question is, what happened to the embedded bangs?  I have tried with and without ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION. I have even tried escaping (^) the bangs in the input file, still with no luck.

Is there any way to preserve them?

Thanks.

Comment: You can preserve exclamation marks by waiting until you're ready to retrieve variable values before enabling delayed expansion.  If you `set` a value containing exclamation marks while delayed expansion is enabled, the exclamation marks get clobbered.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried with and without delayed expansion and they still get clobbered.

Comment: Unable to recreate.  I copypasted bang1.cmd and bang1.txt verbatim and ran bang1, then bang2.  Exclamation marks missing as expected.  I then replaced the second line of bang1.cmd with `setlocal`, leaving out `enabledelayedexpansion`, re-ran, and ended up with exclamation marks included.  By the way, you can eliminate your `:unquotex` function simply by replacing `call :doit %%a` with `call :doit "%%~a"`, then replacing `set P1=%1` with `set "P1=%~1"`.  Also, instead of `if %P1%. EQU .` you should do `if not defined P1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem at all is delayed expansion here.
With delayed expansion, exclamation marks are used to expand variables, but when there is only one exclamation mark in a line it will be removed.

Specially in FOR /F loops delayed expansion is tricky to handle, as the expansion of the FOR parameter is directly affected by the delayed expansion.  The only solution is to disable it temporarily.
The next problem is the `CALL`, you can't transfer content with `CALL` (without destroying it).
It's better to transfer the variable by reference (only the variable name) and then get the content in the called function.
The last problem in your code are the percent expansions, do not use them

when delayed expansion is enabled, as the delayed expansion is evaluated after the percent expansion an expanded line will be expanded a second time by the delayed expansion.
Sample.
Assume the content of var is `Bang!`

`echo %var%` expands to `Bang!` but then the delayed expansion will evaluate `Bang!` to `Bang`.

With `echo !var!` you simply get `Bang!`

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if exist bang2.cmd del bang2.cmd
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (bang1.txt) do (  
  setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
  set "line=%%a"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  call :doit1 line
  endlocal
  endlocal
)
exit /b

:doit1
set "P1=!%1!"
if "!P1!" EQU "" exit /b
call :unquotex P1
echo>>bang2.cmd echo P1:[!P1!]
exit /b

:unquotex
set "param=!%~1!"
if "!param:~0,1!" == ^""" (
    set "param=!param:~1,-1!"
)
set "%1=!param!"
exit /b
```

Comment: @DennisvanGils You are right, and you have to take care of delayed expansion here, a simple `set %1=%~2` doesn't work here

Comment: I know, that's why I removed the need for delayed expansion in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like this :

```
@echo off

(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type bang1.txt') do echo  echo P1:[%%~a])>bang2.cmd
```

Comment: Is that cls really needed? I like this version a lot more than mine though, much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
if exist bang2.cmd del bang2.cmd
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (bang1.txt) do call :doit1 %%a
exit /b

:doit1
set "P1=%1"
if %P1%.==. exit /b
call :unquotex P1 %P1%
echo>>bang2.cmd echo P1:[%P1%]
exit /b

:unquotex
set "%1=%~2"
exit /b
```

Using parameters, you can get the version without quotes using `%~1` instead of `%1`. If `%1` contains `"hello world"` for example, then %~1 contains `hello world`. This allows for an easier unquoting mechanism, removing the need for delayed expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the output file is exactly the same: no bangs.

Comment: @NeilWeicher that's weird, it seems to work fine for me. You didn't add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to your batch-file, did you?

Comment: This is getting more curious.  It seems to work differently on different operating systems.  On Windows 7 x64 and Windows 8.1 x64 no bang. On Windows 2008 Server R2 bang.

Comment: @NeilWeicher No, the difference is that in your batch file `delayed expansion` is enabled. Then the exclamation marks gets a special meaning and behaviour

Comment: @jeb - doh!  Must have been staring at the code for too long. You are right. That was it.